# $p$- subgroups of $Gl_2(q)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

This question is similar to 
[non-abelian groups of order $p^2q^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490441/non-abelian-groups-of-order-p2q2), for which Derek Holt gave an answer to one of the cases, but I am looking for an answer that cover all the cases.

I am looking for $p$ groups of $Gl_2(q)$ for $p,q$ odd primes.
More explicitly, I am looking for subgroups of isomorphism type
$C_p,C_{p^2}, C_p\times C_p$ in $Gl_2(q)$, up to conjugation.

Clearly, the cases to consider are where $p|q-1,p^2|q-1,p|q+1,p^2|q+1$.

My goal is to classify up to isomorphism, all the groups of order $p^2q^2$ which are semi-direct product of the Sylow subgroup $Q\rtimes P$.

I am interested not only in their number but also in their structure, that is the matrices in $Gl_2(q)$ which correspond to the $P$ action.

I will appreciate any help, in an explicit answer or a book reference which have the answer.

p.s any leads on the case where $p=2$ will be great also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can describe the structure of the Sylow $2$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}_2(q)$.

If $4|q-1$, then it is the wreath product $C_{2^k} \wr C_2$, where $2^k$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $q-1$.

If $4|q+1$, then it is isomorphic to the semidihedral group $\langle x,y \mid x^{2^{k+1}}=y^2=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{2^k-1} \rangle$, where $2^k$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $q+1$.

For odd $p$, the Sylow $p$-subgroup is isomorphic to $C_{p^k}^2$ if $p|q-1$, and otherwise it is cyclic.

Comment: Thanks Derek Holt. In addition to the information you gave, I am interested in the number and structure (matrices in $Gl_2(q)$) of the groups, $C_p, C_{p^2},C_p\times C_p$ as subgroups of $Gl_2(q)$. Can you add it to your answer or to give a book reference for this (with proofs)?

Comment: There are too many cases. If you ask a more specific question I will try and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

When $p$ equals 2 and $q$ is 1 modulo 4, the matrices are of the form
$\left( \begin{array}{cc} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{array} \right)$ and
$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \alpha \\ \beta & 0 \end{array} \right)$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ elements of order a power of 2 in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$.

When $p$ is odd and divides $q-1$, the matrices are of the form
$\left( \begin{array}{cc} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{array} \right)$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ elements of order a power of $p$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$.

When $p$ equals 2 and $q$ is 3 modulo 4, or when $p$ is odd and divides $q+1$, one can build matrices representatives by considering $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ as a two-dimensionnal vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ (i.e. the multiplicative group of the extended finite field) of order a power of $p$ have an action on the vector space that can be computed explicitely. The multiplicative group of a finite field being cyclic, you just need to compute a single matrix that generates the Sylow-subgroup when $p$ is odd. When $p$ is equal to 2, you also need to include a matrix representing the action of the Frobenius automorphism.

The matrices described above generate one $p$-Sylow-subgroups, since orders match with answers provided by Derek Holt. The other ones are obtained via arbitrary conjugation.