# reference for classifying groups of order $p^2q^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

In a previous question I asked about the number and structure of groups of order $p^2q^2$ where $p,q$ are primes and with the help of Prof. Derek Holt I understand it now (see here [non-abelian groups of order $p^2q^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490441/non-abelian-groups-of-order-p2q2))

I understood that there is a full classification of such groups from the beginning of the previous century which I want to use as reference but I couldn't find it.

I will be grateful if someone can direct me to the first paper it appears is, or at least to another source.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groups of order $p^2q^2$ for $p,q$ prime were initially determined by Le Vavasseur (1899 and 1902), and later by Lin (1974). They were also enumerated by Laue (1982). Both Laue and Lin get identical results, although Lin's summary has a counting error. All such groups are solvable, and have either a normal Sylow $p$-group or normal Sylow $q$-group.

Reference: [Bibliography on the classification of finite groups](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=39&ved=0ahUKEwicseDG153NAhXNSxoKHbUNCwA4HhAWCFQwCA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.auckland.ac.nz%2F~obrien%2Fresearch%2Fbibliography.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG-0ordNBlAZCmKjUWQ0D06S-xFIQ&sig2=C4pPlOVBTfKog4dpRinHBQ) by E.A. O'Brien.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Another question. The book by Laue is in German, the papers by Le Vavasseur are in French. I think that the paper by Lin is in English but I couldn't found it. Do you know if there is an accessible reference in English to this work?